# How to transmit form-data without POST with python requests?

Tags: python, html, forms, python-requests

I'm writing a little piece of python code to login on several "Investing"-Websites of mine and get out the current amount of money invested. I'm using pythons requests library and analyze the html-source to identify the form and the fields to fill in.

So, a form may look like this:

```
<form class="onboarding-form" id="loginForm" action="https://estateguru.co/portal/login/authenticate" method="post" data-redirect="https://estateguru.co/portal/home">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control main-input" name="username">
                <label class="bmd-label-floating main-label">E-Mail</label>
                <em id="username-error" class="error bmd-help help-block" style="display:none;">This field is required.</em>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" class="form-control main-input login-pass" name="password">
                <label class="bmd-label-floating main-label long-label">Passwort (Mindestens 8 Zeichen)</label>
                <em id="password-error" class="error bmd-help help-block" style="display:none;">This field is required.</em>
                <a href="#" class="show-pass-icon"><i class="zmdi zmdi-eye"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In this case, my code looks like this:

```
import requests
_username = 'xxx'
_password = 'yyy'

loginUrl = 'https://estateguru.co/portal/login/authenticate'
readUrl = 'https://estateguru.co/portal/portfolio/overview'
with requests.session() as s:
    
    payload = {"username": _username, "password": _password}

    final = s.post(loginUrl, data = payload)
    result = s.get(readUrl)
    print(result)
```

This works like a charm for many websites! But now i got an website without the "method=post" in the form, so i don't know hot to transmit the form-data.
The html-part (from http://www.reinvest24.com/en/login) looks like this:

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email" value="" name="email" maxLength="100" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" value="" name="password" maxLength="100" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
    <p class="forgot text-right">
        <a href="/en/forgot-password"><span>Forgot password?</span></a>
    </p>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Login"/>
        <p class="reg text-center">
            <span>Don&#x27;t have an account?</span>
             <a href="/en/registration">
            <span>Sign up</span></a>
        </p>
</form>
```

So without the method clarified, I tried

```
final = s.get(loginUrl, data = payload)
```

but without success. The result in both cases is a html-output saying something about "Loading authorization details...".

So my question is: Am i missing the right method (POST/GET) to transmit data or am i missing some other parameter? Some websites require a session-token, which I retrieve from the login-site itself (like it's the case in https://www.mintos.com/de/login), but in my opinion, this is not the problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the body (form data) of a HTTP request is ignored when the method is set to GET. Therefore you shouldn't try to submit the request via GET (not only is it not safe to transmit sensitive info over GET, the server would just ignore the username/password of your request).

The issue here is that the page is doing some JavaScript magic to submit your request over a different URL. Open up your web inspector and watch the "network" tab whenever you try to login on that website. You should see that the request is being POSTed to `https://api-frontend.reinvest24.com/graphql`.

When we inspect this POST request, we can see that the data is being transmitted as a JSON body, not a form body. So your request should look something along the lines of this:

```py
login_url = 'https://api-frontend.reinvest24.com/graphql'
payload = {
    "operationName": "login",
    "variables": {
        "email": EMAIL,
        "password": PASSWORD
    },
    "query": "mutation login($email: String!, $password: String!) {\n  login(email: $email, password: $password)\n}\n"
}
r = s.post(url=login_url, json=payload)

# note that we used the 'json' parameter here not 'data'
```

Chrome web inspector is your friend here to observe how data is transmitted when logging in.

Good luck!

Comment: Great Advice, thank you! I think i succesfully loged in now, because i get a kind of session-ID if i print out r and otherwise an error code if i mess up the password on purpose. Now i have to analyze the HavaScript magic happens after login, because simply doing a GET on 'https://www.reinvest24.com/en/my-investments' is not working. But you open my eyes concerning the network tab and the json-parameters, so thank you very much!